# Subquery for particular field value during INSERT from Table1 to Table2 in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, subquery, toad

I'm attempting to create a short script which will take all of the fields from Table1 and insert them into Table2. The basic fields (col1, col2, col3, etc.) I have got covered by something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7)
             SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, SYSDATE, USER
FROM Table1
```

I am having trouble though inserting the values for 2 fields in particular, `col12/col13` of Table2. These columns are standalone in Table1, but in my new Table2 there the value referenced via foreign key `ID` to `Table3/Table4`. I'm now attempting to figure out how to do a proper subquery during my table INSERT from Table1 into Table2.

To try and better explain:

```
// Previously Used for DB
[Table1]
col12 -- CUSTOMER
col13 -- MERCHANT

//---------------
// NEW
[Table2]
col15 -- CUSTOMER_ID
col16 -- MERCHANT_ID

[Table3]
ID
CUSTOMER_DESC
CREATED_DATE
CREATED_BY

[Table4]
ID
MERCHANT_DESC
CREATED_DATE
CREATED_BY
```

Can anyone provide an example of the proper formatting for such a thing within my INSERT script? I'm envisioning it being something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, [SELECT ID FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.CUSTOMER_DESC == Table2.CUSTOMER])
FROM Table2
```

My apologies if explanation isn't the clearest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to properly `JOIN` to `Table3`, `Table4` in order to get the referenced field values:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (CUSTOMER_ID, MERCHANT_ID, col1, col2, etc...)
SELECT t3.ID, t4.ID, t1.col1, t2.col2, etc..
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.CUSTOMER = t3.CUSTOMER_DESC
INNER JOIN Table4 t4 ON t1.MERCHANT = t4.MERCHANT_DESC
```

There should be no problem with the above query *provided that* there is a 1-1 relationship between `Table1` and `Table3` on fields `CUSTOMER`,  `CUSTOMER_DESC` and `Table1` and `Table4` on fields `MERCHANT`,  `MERCHANT_DESC`.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e570/3)

Comment: Hmm... when I try the following, my 'alias' for Table1 is flagging with `Found: 'T1' Expecting OF`? --- `INSERT into Table2 (Model_ID, Vendor_ID, col1, col2, col3, etc...) SELECT T3.ID, T4.ID, T1.col1, t1.col2, etc... FROM Table1 as T1 INNER JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T1.MODEL = T3.Model_Description INNER JOIN Table4 as T4 ON T1.VENDOR_NAME = T4.Vendor_Name`

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic The query is working fine with the schema you posted. Have a look at the sqlfiddle demo I've setup. Are there any differences between the schema of the demo and the actual schema?

Comment: In Oracle, you do not use the "AS" keyword when aliasing a table.  Sounds like it is trying to interpret that as a flashback query and expecting to see "AS OF".  Just use "Table T1" and so on.

Comment: @DaveCosta That was it! I work mainly in SQL Server where `AS` is used for aliasing. The fiddle demo posted works because `AS` was omitted.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, my apologies if this question is pretty 'green'. I figured out the issue seems to have been my use of (ex.) `Table1 as T1` when instead I needed simply `Table1 T1`. I am noticing an issue though. Piecing my query part by part with the joins to investigate only the `SELECT` portion, the `SELECT` if fine and loads expected data when I'm only selecting T1 columns, but if I add `INNER JOIN Table3 T3 on T1.MODEL = T3.MODEL_DESCRIPTION` then zero data is returned? I have an Index set, but no actual `FK` yet explicitly set. Is that causing no data to return?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic `FK` is only necessary for referential integrity. You should get some data returned if there are actual matches between `Table1` and `Table3`. Try executing only the `SELECT` statement of the `INSERT`. Do you get any records returned?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, yes, I believe what you mentioned is what I was trying to explain in the above. If I do `SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2, etc... FROM Table1 T1 ` I get data as expected. However if I add the Join:  `SELECT T3.ID as ModelID, T1.col1, T1.col2, etc... FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.Model = T3.Model_Description` then I receive `No rows returned`?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic In this case there are no records having `T1.Model = T3.Model_Description`. Can you setup a fiddle demo with some actual data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, yea, I think you are correct here. My `INV_Models` table (Table3) only has 7 records currently (Test Data during Development). Thus none of the records in Table1 are having a corresponding match. In the grand scheme I'm trying to write this DB conversion script (many more fields in the new setup with better integrity), but I'm trying to figure out that fine line between attempting to script parts of conversion and forcing the user to go in and modify records (1350 currently). Records in Table1 for this field (ex.) are `dc 7800` and `DC7800`. I can't see an easy wayto check all.

Answer (score -1):

You almost got it right.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2, col3, col12)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, (SELECT customer_desc FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.ID = Table2.col15)
FROM Table2
```

Comment: This will not compile.  there is no reference to table2 in the subselect.  Its also possible that you would get multiple records back using this method which would also cause an error.